# json unicode to string so i can use that in django html page

Tags: python, json, django, unicode

**Edited :**

Anybody tell me how to decode the unicode.I just want to print json unicode into my html page i developed. I got the api from [heroku api](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapify.heroku.com%2Fresources%2F4fda2ede485abc0001000034&ei=ytu8U9qqFYqwuASj_ICoDA&usg=AFQjCNFA44iaXXsuzNX9RrchrnryRRkLRA&bvm=bv.70138588,d.c2E).

pretty much i followed every step correctly. But the output is unicode and that i don`t know how to extract the content and display into my page.

I need to print the content. How to do that ?

my views.py

```
template_vars['kural'] = json.dumps(thirukural[x])
        t = loader.get_template('index.html')
        c = Context(template_vars)
        #pprint.pprint(c)

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Html Page

```
  <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head><body>

<p id="p"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var t = {{kural|safe}}
var text = eval(t);
var p = document.getElementById("p");
p.innerHTML=t.kural;
</script>
</body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

It`s currently printed like this

```
யாதனின் யாதனின் நீங்கியான் நோதல் அதனின் அதனின் இலன்.
```

but in the heroku api page the sample output printed like this

```
  {
  "id": "213",
  "kural": "புத்தே ளுலகத்தும் ஈண்டும் பெறலரிதே\n\nஒப்புரவின் நல்ல பிற."
  }
```

You can see that my output doesnt have `line breaks that \n` . How can i do that ?

Comment: have you tried {{kural|safe}} ?

Comment: thirukural[x] contains the same its printed in HTML page

Comment: ya i tried {{ kural|safe }} also same result only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kural` variable is a dict, if you want to display `kural` in your view, I think you need json.

```
import json
template_vars['kural'] = json.dumps(thirukural[x])
```

Comment: well i tried what you are suggested. Its removed the u' , and html nothing changed so my friend came up with one idea . I edited my question please see and help me.

Comment: Any how i am asking that question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you'll want to do is change that first line you show of your views code to:

`template_vars['kural'] = thirukural[x].encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`

That should change everything into HTML entities and it will end up looking something like this:

`'&#2953;&#2994;&#2965;&#2990;&#3021; &#2980;&#2996;&#3008;&#2951;&#2991; &#2980;&#3018;&#2975;&#3021;&#2986;&#2990;&#3021; &#2990;&#2994;&#2992;&#3021;&#2980;&#2994;&#3009;&#2990;&#3021;\n\n&#2965;&#3010;&#2990;&#3021;&#2986;&#2994;&#3009;&#2990;&#3021; &#2951;&#2994;&#3021;&#2994; &#2980;&#2993;&#3007;&#2997;&#3009;.'`

Comment: well now the error is 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: actually it`s replace the char only but i need text back from that unicode. How can i get it ?

Comment: Those characters are HTML entities which should render properly in a web browser when you output them in a template. You may have to filter it through safe though.

Comment: well i give up. i tried safe but return i tired. Anyhow now output what expected but the line break not working correctly. Can you please guide me